# Why do rounded dividers look terrible in Firefox, and normal in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, html, css

I just tried to make a rounded divider in Firefox and it looks terrible. Here's the simple code:

```
<html>
<style>
hr.rounded {
  border-top: 15px solid #bbb;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
<body>
<hr class="rounded">
</body>
</html>
```

And here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mnfq9bu2/

The even stranger thing is that it looks perfectly normal in Chrome. Does anyone know what's going on? Thanks.

Comment: Can you include screenshots of the rounded divider in the various browsers and indicate what about it is incorrect or undesirable? Also, this question probably belongs on StackOverflow. No, don't repost it there. Give us a bit of time and we can likely get the community member votes to send it over there automatically.

Comment: To be honest, I think Firefox actually displays what is written in the CSS  ,,, changing it to `border-block: 7px solid #bbb; border-inline: 1px solid #bbb;` makes it look good in both
`

Comment: Think about what your CSS does ... it places a 15 pixel top border and sets the border radius ... the bottom border is absent (or maybe 1px in a HR, not sure) how do you put a 8 pixel radius on a 0/1 pixel border? Chrome gets it wrong in my opinion

Comment: actually adding `border:solid #bbb 1px;` before `border-top` will fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox seems to be doing the right thing - rounding only the top border.

To get a consistent look across browsers you could scrap using borders altogether and instead have the body of the hr with the 15px height and remove the default border.

```html
<style>
  hr.rounded {
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 15px;
    background: #bbb;
    border: solid transparent 0px;
  }
</style>
<html>

<body>
  <hr class="rounded">
</body>

</html>
```

Note: this method is suggested rather than try alternatives like split the border between top and bottom because systems can struggle to display part CSS pixels correctly.